# How to change Jenkins Node details through python jenkinsapi

Tags: python, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-cli

I have read lots of Jenkins API documents. But I didn't get any way to changes the details of the Jenkins node using Python API. 
basically, these are the fields I want to change:

1) # of executors
2) Labels
3) Host

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/78dSN.png)

Answer (score 0):

```
import jenkins.model.*
import hudson.model.*
import hudson.slaves.*
import hudson.plugins.sshslaves.*
import java.util.ArrayList;
import hudson.slaves.EnvironmentVariablesNodeProperty.Entry;

  Slave slave = new DumbSlave(
                    "agent-node","Agent node description",
                    "/home/jenkins",
                    "1",
                    Node.Mode.NORMAL,
                    "agent-node-label",
                    new SSHLauncher("agenNode",22,"user","password","","","","",""),
                    new RetentionStrategy.Always(),
                    new LinkedList())
  Jenkins.instance.addNode(slave)
```

Comment: I am very much new to groovy code. I have gone through some of the tutorials but didn't get much info. Could please provide me the information how we can execute this groovy code and some basic knowledge.

Comment: to run the script , Jenkins --> manage -->  script console  and just copy the script and run it or your jenkinshost:8080/script

Comment: @Mor Lajb the question is about "using Python API", your script doesn't seem to be python